# hlsl nointerpolation behaviour

Tags: graphics, directx, hlsl

For an experiment I want to pass all edges of a triangle to the pixel shader and manually calculate the pixel position with the triangle edges and bayrcentric coodinates.
In order to do this I wrote a geometry shader that passes all edges of my triangle to the pixel shader:

```
struct GeoIn
{
    float4 projPos : SV_POSITION;
    float3 position : POSITION;
};

struct GeoOut
{
    float4 projPos : SV_POSITION;
    float3 position : POSITION;
    float3 p[3] : TRIPOS;
};

[maxvertexcount(3)]
void main(triangle GeoIn i[3], inout TriangleStream<GeoOut> OutputStream)
{
    GeoOut o;

    // add triangle data
    for(uint idx = 0; idx < 3; ++idx)
    {
        o.p[idx] = i[idx].position;
    }

    // generate verices
    for(idx = 0; idx < 3; ++idx)
    {
        o.projPos = i[idx].projPos;
        o.position = i[idx].position;

        OutputStream.Append(o);
    }

    OutputStream.RestartStrip();
}
```

The pixel shader outputs the manually reconstructed position:

```
struct PixelIn
{
    float4 projPos : SV_POSITION;
    float3 position : POSITION;
    float3 p[3] : TRIPOS;
    float3 bayr : SV_Barycentrics;
};

float4 main(PixelIn i) : SV_TARGET
{
    float3 pos = i.bayr.x * i.p[0] + i.bayr.y * i.p[1] + i.bayr.z * i.p[2];
    return float4(abs(pos), 1.0);
}
```

And I get the following (expected) result:
[image]

However, when I modify my `PixelIn` struct by adding `nointerpolation` to `p[3]`:

```
struct PixelIn
{
    ...
    nointerpolation float3 p[3] : TRIPOS;
};
```

I get:
[image]

I did not expect a different result because I am not changing the values of `p[]` for a single triangle in the geometry shader. I tried debugging it by changing the output to `float4(abs(i.p[0]), 1.0);` with and without interpolation. Without `nointerpolation` the values of `p[]` do not vary within a triangle (which makes sense, because all should have the same value). With `nointerpolation` the values of `p[]` do change slightly. Why is that the case? I thought `nointerpolate` was not supposed to interpolate anything.

---

Edit:
This is the wireframe of my geometry:
[image: wireframe]

Comment: Can you share a wireframe view of the input?

Comment: I added the wireframe